# How to provide separate SSL certificate for specified path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, passenger

I have Rails app running behind Nginx using Passenger. SSL is configured at Nginx side in *server* block and works fine. Now I need specify separate certificate on certain path, say for https://example.com/blablabla.

I need this because of constrains of some system I working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A certificate identifies a server and not a path inside the server. The path is only known after the SSL handshake is done, that is after the certificate was already provided. Thus it is not possible to have one certificate for a specific path and another certificate for another path and the same hostname.